# Rendering text in uppercase without changing the backing string? (iOS7 & Text Kit)

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios7, textkit

My application targets iOS 7 only. I have a `UITextView` presenting an `NSAttributedString`. The string represents a document, each paragraph has a number of attributes set on it for styling. Some paragraphs need to be rendered in ALL CAPS, however, the style of the paragraph could be changed by the user to something with regular capitalization, so the original capitalization of the string must be preserved.

How would I go about doing this? My first thought is to use the new Text Kit features and do some sort of glyph replacement, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how that would work. Another thought would be to create a custom font, where all of the characters are uppercase.

Again, I can't just change the backing string, so something like `uppercaseString` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Having just been working on some TextKit stuff, I'll take a stab at this.

I'd create a custom NSLayoutManager subclass and override:

```
- (void)setGlyphs:(const CGGlyph *)glyphs properties:(const NSGlyphProperty *)props characterIndexes:(const NSUInteger *)charIndexes font:(UIFont *)aFont forGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange
```

Inside this method you'll need to do your own glyph generation, which, while it sounds hard as outlined in the CoreText docs on "[Getting Glyphs for Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/FontOperations/FontOperations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW12)." Basically all you'll need to do is grab the characters from `self.textStorage` that are referenced by `characterIndexes` and use `CFStringCapitalize()` to make it all caps.

Note the docs on the `-setGlyphs:…` method, as it has some oddities.

Hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: This answer is spot on, the only thing I would add is that you don't need to subclass `NSLayoutManager` if you use the layout manager's delegate method `layoutManager:shouldGenerateGlyphs:properties:characterIndexes:font:forGlyphRange:`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but as no one posted a working answer, here is one. My knowledge of `CFStringRef` manipulation and bridging to ARC is a bit limited, as shown below. Feel free to correct my code.

In your `NSLayoutManagerDelegate`, implement `shouldGenerateGlyphs`:

```objectivec
-(NSUInteger)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager shouldGenerateGlyphs:(const CGGlyph *)glyphs properties:(const NSGlyphProperty *)props characterIndexes:(const NSUInteger *)charIndexes font:(NSFont *)aFont forGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange {
    // Get correct indices
    NSUInteger location = charIndexes[0];
    NSUInteger length = glyphRange.length;
    
    // Create string reference and convert to uppercase
    CFStringRef str = (__bridge CFStringRef)[self.textStorage.string substringWithRange:(NSRange){ location, length }];
    CFMutableStringRef uppercase = CFStringCreateMutable(NULL, CFStringGetLength(str));
    CFStringAppend(uppercase, str);
    CFStringUppercase(uppercase, NULL);
    
    // Create glyphs for our new uppercase string
    CGGlyph *newGlyphs = GetGlyphsForCharacters((__bridge CTFontRef)(aFont), uppercase);
    [self.layoutManager setGlyphs:newGlyphs properties:props characterIndexes:charIndexes font:aFont forGlyphRange:glyphRange];
    free(newGlyphs);

    return glyphRange.length;
}

CGGlyph* GetGlyphsForCharacters(CTFontRef font, CFStringRef string)
{
    // Get the string length.
    CFIndex count = CFStringGetLength(string);
 
    // Allocate our buffers for characters and glyphs.
    UniChar *characters = (UniChar *)malloc(sizeof(UniChar) * count);
    CGGlyph *glyphs = (CGGlyph *)malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * count);
 
    // Get the characters from the string.
    CFStringGetCharacters(string, CFRangeMake(0, count), characters);
 
    // Get the glyphs for the characters.
    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, characters, glyphs, count);
 
    // Free the buffers
    free(characters);
    return glyphs;
}
```

I'm using this code successfully in a monospaced text app, and it probably won't be as stable in a use case which requires more elaborate scripts.